Ejected create-react-app and v5 webpack migration - onBeforeSetupMiddleware and onAfterSetupMiddleware
I maintain a project for my job that was built using create-react-app. We have strict compliance standards for removing issues, which led to us ejecting said project a while back. An issue on webpack-dev-server 4.15.2 is prompting us to upgrade, which brings us to major version upgrade 5.1.0. The problem is that the webpackDevServer.config.js is outdated, and I can't figure out how to migrate the follwoing chunk of code
    onBeforeSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
      devServer.app.use(evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer));

      if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
        require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app);
      }
    },
    onAfterSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
      devServer.app.use(redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
      devServer.app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
    }

to be in the new SetupMiddlewares function.
Every migration doc I'm finding uses devServer.app.get inside the middleware blocks to be upgraded instead of devServer.app.use, and everything I've tried that gets yarn start to actually work gives me a connection error in chrome.
:(
This site can't be reached
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I tried the following based on this, and no dice.
setupMiddlewares(middleware, devServer) {
      if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
        // This registers user provided middleware for proxy reasons
        require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app);
      }
      // Use the `unshift` method if you want to run a middleware before all other middlewares
      // or when you are migrating from the `onBeforeSetupMiddleware` option
      middlewares.unshift(
      devServer.app.use(evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer));
      );

      // Use the `push` method if you want to run a middleware after all other middlewares
      // or when you are migrating from the `onAfterSetupMiddleware` option
      middlewares.push(      
        devServer.app.use(redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
      );
      middlewares.push(
devServer.app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
      );

}

The same question has been asked on their github project here, seemingly with no answer.
I also think the problem could be related to attempting to migrate the https: getHttpsConfig() line. I have the following:
    server: {
      type: 'https',
      options: {...getHttpsConfig()}
    },


I'm pretty sure you need to return middlewares at the end

Thanks, good catch. Unfortunately still get the same behavior - IDE says project compiled successfully and webpack compiled successfully with no issues found, but localhost still shows me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
